# Ability to SUM() or GROUP BY from the template or ElementCriteriaModel

Tags: entries, elementcriteriamodel

After twitter conversation with Brandon Kelly, is it possible to implement something similar to the following?

```
craft.entries.section("mySection").sum("myCustomField")
```

Answer (score 6):

You could do this with a plugin. Create a [Variable](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/variables) class with a function called `sum()`, which accepts an ElementCriteriaModel, passes it to ElementsService::buildElementsQuery(), and then replaces the `SELECT` value on the resulting DbCommand object:

```php
<?php
namespace Craft;

class FooVariable
{
    public function sum(ElementCriteriaModel $criteria, $column)
    {
        $query = craft()->elements->buildElementsQuery($criteria);

        if ($query)
        {
            return $query
                ->select("SUM({$column})")
                ->group(null)
                ->queryScalar();
        }
    }
}
```

With that in place, you can do this in your templates:

```twig
{% set entries = craft.entries.section("mySection") %}
{% set sum = craft.foo.sum(entries, "field_myCustomField") %}
```

Note that you will need to pass in the field’s full column name (with that “field_” prefix) rather than just its handle. You can figure that out by looking at your craft_content table (or craft_matrixcontent_matrixfieldhandle if it’s a Matrix field). It would have been possible to get the code to be smart enough to figure the column name out for itself, but this way is a bit simpler.

Comment: Perfect. The only thing I had to change slightly was the return from `return $query->select("SUM({$column})")->queryScalar();` to `return $query->select("SUM({$column})")->group(null)->queryScalar();` So I could get the complete total for what I needed

Comment: Perfect ! I confirm the `->group(null)` addition to make the total.

Answer (score 5):

In Craft 3 you can do this without a plugin:

```
{% set hours = craft.entries
    .section('channelTimetracking')
    .sum('field_myCustomField')
?? null %}
```

Details in the [docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/#query-execution).

Comment: I just discovered, if you are summing matrix fields, you need to do this: field_matrixBlockName_fieldName.