# Sum with a group by Author

Tags: plugin-development, database, query

I am trying to build a leaderboard page, and I'm having difficulties finding a way to group the entries by Author.

I was able to create a plugin to get the sql sum function in there, but I now need to add a group by Author and order by Score DESC to that.

First steps were taken from here: [Ability to SUM() or GROUP BY from the template or ElementCriteriaModel](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1687/ability-to-sum-or-group-by-from-the-template-or-elementcriteriamodel)

What I ultimately want is a query that would look like this (very simplified of course):

```
SELECT author, SUM(content.score) as score FROM content Group By Author Order By score DESC
```

Is there a way to do this "natively" or do I need to write my own query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but I created this little function in a Variable class.  I get all the necessary info (username and score) in an array.  Works fine for what I needed.

```
public function leaderboard(ElementCriteriaModel $criteria)
   {
       $query = craft()->elements->buildElementsQuery($criteria);

   if ($query)
   {
      $query
          ->select("authorId, SUM(field_score) as score, users.username as username")
          ->join("users", "users.id = authorId" )
          ->group("authorId")
          ->order("score DESC");

               return $query->queryAll();
       }
   }
```